# How to paginate asyncio requests in python where total is provided in header

Tags: python, asynchronous, pagination, python-requests, python-asyncio

*Just to clarify in advance, I use Postman to test my requests and they return the results im looking for.

I'm connecting to an API using Python. The API will only return 500 records per request and it will provide the total number of records in the first response header 'x-test-count'

I'm obviously not python savvy and feel that im handling pagination completely wrong. Take a look at the async get function. Basically, it takes the total count from the first response and loops through running

```
                            async with session.get(paging_url) as response:

                                page_results = await response.json()

                                pages.extend(page_results)
```

It does return results but only 500. So it would seem that its not capturing each iteration.

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self, id, type):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.requests = []

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.queue_list = []
        self.coroutines = []
        self.headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-test-token': self.token,
        }

    def get_id(self, type=''):
        id = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m-%d%H-%M%S-') + str(uuid4())
        if type != '':
            id = type + '-' + id
        return id

    def url_encode(self, url):

        # doesn't like encoding urls using yarl. I'm manually handling them below with UTF-8 encode
        url = url.replace(' ', '%20')
        #url = url.replace('?', '%3F')

        return url

    def queue_create(self, type=''):

        id = self.get_id(type='queue')

        if type == '':
            self.debug('Error: queue_create was not given a type')
            return

        id = Queue(id=id, type=type)
        self.debug('queue_create instantiated new queue class named: ' + id)

        # TODO: Add to list of active queues to track for create and destroy

        # Return name of new object
        return id

    def queue_run(self, name=''):
        self.debug('Starting queue_run')

        if name == '':
            self.debug('Error: queue_run asked to run without providing a name')
            #return

        **async def get(url, headers):
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)) as session:
                async with session.get(url) as response:
                    self.debug('HTTP Response: ' + str(response.status))
                    # Set pagination vars to 1
                    current_page = 1
                    page_range = 1
                    # Check the status code. If other than 200, stop
                    assert response.status == 200
                    # Get the count of records. If not provided, set last_page to 1
                    try:
                        page_range = int(response.headers['x-test-count'])
                        self.debug(response.headers['x-test-count'])
                    except:
                        self.debug('x-test-count not provided, defaulted to 1')
                    first_page_results = await response.json()
                    if page_range == 1:
                        self.debug('Returning first page results only')
                        return first_page_results
                    else:
                        self.debug('Total results: ' + str(page_range) + '. Performing additional requests.')
                        pages = []
                        for records in range(1,page_range,500):
                            remaining_records = page_range - records
                            if remaining_records > 500:
                                paging_size = 500
                            else:
                                paging_size = remaining_records
                            # Create the paging URL
                            paging_url = url + '&size=' + str(paging_size) + '&from=' + str(records)
                            # Run paged requests
                            async with session.get(paging_url) as response:
                                page_results = await response.json()
                                # combine paged requests
                                pages.extend(page_results)
                            # Clear paging URL
                            paging_url = ''
                    return pages**

        # Establish the loop
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        # Establish coroutines and populate with queries from queue
        coroutines = []

        for query in self.queue:

            # Removed a lot of the actual code here. Basically, this establishes the URL and appends coroutines
                coroutines.append(get(url, headers=headers))


        # Start the asyncio loop

        results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coroutines))

        return results

    def add_request(self, type, endpoint, query='', deleted=False, data='', full=False, paging_size='', paging_from=''):

        self.debug('Starting add_request')
        self.debug('Queue before append: ', item=self.queue)

        self.queue.append([type, endpoint, query, deleted, data, full, paging_size, paging_from]) 
        self.debug('Queue after append: ', item=self.queue)

        return self.queue
```

So to run, it looks something like this

```
Test = Test()

Test.add_request('read', 'personnel', '', full=True ,deleted=False)

response = Test.queue_run()
```